# How i can get log message with yii2

Tags: php, yii2

i have a little problem.
I'm developing a php application using Yii2 framework and i want to save a log messagges into db table.
I'm coding my own component witch extends DbTarget, in this component i rewrite export() function to save data into my table. It's works fine, but i can't get the log message.
For example, when i call Yii:log('message log'), all my data are saved in my db except 'message log' because i don't know how to get this value in my component.

Any solutions?
thanks

P.s. I'm newbee with yii2 and i have read the official documentation, but i didn't find any solution.

Comment: Share some code. Please see [ask] and [mcve] to get you started on posting a good question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you should specify level of the message

```
Yii:log('message log', Logger::LEVEL_TRACE);
```

or use shortcut methods

```
Yii::info('message log');
Yii::trace('message log');
Yii::error('message log');
```

Check your config for another targets. May be your message goes to level or category of another target. Notice that default category is `'application'`.

To be shure you can make this configuration

```
'components' => [
    'log' => [
        'targets' => [
            [
                'class' => 'YourDbTarget',
                'levels' => ['info'],
                'categories' => ['application'],
            ],
        ],
    ],
],
```

And try to log info message

```
Yii::info('message log'); // target = info, category = application
```

Comment: Tnx, now i can see log message in my debug toolbar, but in my component witch function i 'll must call to get my log message? for example to get user ID i'll call  'Yii::$app->user->getId();' and save them to my db table. There is something like that call to get my log message? ('message log')  ?

Comment: I think you should make a query to the log table: (new Query)->select('*')->from('log')->all();